# I want to place 4 images in large screen 3 images on medium and 2 images on small in a row but images are changing lines not appearing in a row

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to display 4 images in large screen in a row 3 on medium and 2 on small and 1 on extra small but images are appearing on another line they are not side by side i am fetching images from database.

```
    <div class="row">

    <?php 
            $get_product=get_product($con,'latest',8);
            foreach($get_product as $list){
        ?>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="item py-2">

            <div id="product" class="text-center">
                <div class="image">
                    <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $list['id']?>"><img
                            src="<?php echo PRODUCT_IMAGE_SITE_PATH.$list['image'] ?>" /></a>
                </div>

                <div class="detail py-2">
                    <h6 class="font-size-12">
                        <?php echo $list['name']?>
                    </h6>
                    <div class="rating text-warning">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price font-size-12 m-2">
                        <div class="new-price">Price <span><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <?php echo $list['price']?>
                            </span></div>
                        <div class="old-price">MRP <span><s><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <?php echo $list['mrp']?>
                                </s></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning font-size-12">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
            }
        ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Use card-deck => remove the col(s) from the for loop, set a unique id instead of #product. Set the desired widths in CSS with flex-basis, -shrink and -grow and override with media queries.

Comment: thank u but i want to use cols

Comment: That's fine, embrace the complexity of finetuning the bootstrap grid layout utility classes in a responsive way. Ideally and the correct way is to introduce your row into the for loop. All rows have, by default, a max. of 12 columns. If you add more you'll introduce padding issues on mobile. Achievable with modulus operator (%4) and rest switch: if rest = 2 => col-lg-6 and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

See here my implementation of Bootstrap's grid layout when giving a random amount of items to a repeater (for loop).

Notice I've implemented it both ways:

- all items inside a single row
- all items divided over multiple rows

This example is developed in React (with an older Bootstrap version), but don't let that stop you as the logic is all the same. One big difference, my solution only requires 3 items per row. You have all of the work cut out for you to implement for 4 items per row.

You want to use colums ... good luck ;)

```
//this.fillRowPerRow();
this.fillAllInOneRow(); 

/**
 * Generates a row for a single full-width card
 * @param {Array<>} card : array of a single card
 */
generateFullRow(card) {
    const column = <div className="col-xs-12">{card}</div>;
    this.rows.push(<div className="row" rel="faq-teaser-list">{column}</div>);
}

/**
 * Generates a row for two or three cards
 * @param {Array<>} cards : array of 2 or 3 cards
 */
generateRow(cards) {
    const columns = [],
        css = cards.length === 3 ? 'col-lg-4' : '';

    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        const card = <div className={`col-md-6 ${css}`}>{cards[i]}</div>;
        columns.push(card);
    }

    this.rows.push(<div className="row" rel="faq-teaser-list">{columns}</div>);
}

/**
 * Generates a row for all cards
 * @param {Array<>} cards
 */
generateSingleRow(cards) {
    const columns = [],
        len = cards.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        const card = <div className={`${this.getColumnClasses(len, i)}`}>{cards[i]}</div>;
        columns.push(card);
    }

    this.rows.push(<div className="row" rel="faq-teaser-list">{columns}</div>);
}

/**
 * Usefull if you fill multiple rows for each set of col 12
 */
fillRowPerRow() {
    let startSlice = 0;
    const rows = Math.ceil(this.faqThemeCards.slice(startSlice).length / 3);

    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++, startSlice+=3) {
        const cards = this.faqThemeCards.slice(startSlice, startSlice + 3);

        switch (cards.length) {
        case 1: this.generateFullRow(cards);
            break;
        default: this.generateRow(cards);
            break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Usefull if you fill a single row with all cols
 */
fillAllInOneRow() {
    //this.generateFullRow(this.faqThemeCards.slice(0, 1));
    this.generateSingleRow(this.faqThemeCards);
} 

/**
 * Decides the responsive classes required for the columns in a single row
 * This can be omitted when resolved in CSS (flex, -grow, -shrink)
 * @param {number} len : length of the array
 * @param {number} idx : index of the current item
 * @returns string for the css classes on a single column
 */
getColumnClasses(len, idx) {
    const mod2 = len % 2,
        mod3 = len % 3;

    let css = 'col-md-6 col-lg-4';

    if (mod2 !== 0) {
        if (idx === len - 1) {
            css = 'col-md-12 col-lg-4';
        }
    }

    if (mod3 !== 0) {
        if (mod3 === 1 && idx >= len - 1) {
            if (mod2 === 0) {
                css = 'col-md-6 col-lg-12';
            } else {
                css = 'col-xs-12';
            }
        }

        if (mod3 === 2 && idx >= len - 2) {
            if (mod2 === 0) {
                css = 'col-md-6';
            } else {
                if (idx === len - 2) {
                    css = 'col-md-6';
                } else {
                    css = 'col-xs-12 col-lg-6';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return css;
}
```

Comment: thank u for the answer, actually i solved that problem by placing cols right below row i had used another div between row and col, but i think that should not be the problem bcoz i am following a video and in the video that man used div between row and col and it didn't create any issue ,i dont know why in my code its creating issue...after removing that div now all images are in a row and taking space as i wanted....thank u for your answer

Comment: Good it works for you! I'm curious for the video to be honest ^^

Comment: in the video at 36:01 timing he will show the code where he used row->div->div->col and its working good if you follow his video then you will see many places where he used divs between row and col

Comment: i am learning php and bootstrap 4 through projects,when i searched i found their videos